# How to concatenate two csv files horizontally to one dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

Suppose I have two csv files / pandas data_frames

```
file1.csv -> 
   file  A
   ---------
0   K0  E1
1   K0  E2
2   K0  E3
3   K1  W1
4   K2  W2

file2.csv ->
   file  B
   --------
0   K0  E3
1   K0  W3
2   K1  E4
3   K1  W4
4   K3  W5
```

How to merge/concatenate them to get a resultant csv ->

```
   file  A   B
   ------------
0   K0  E1  E3
1   K0  E2  W3
2   K0  E3  NA
3   K1  W1  E4
4   K1  NA  W4
5   K2  W2  NA
6   K3  NA  W5
```

NA -> Not Applicable/ Blank/ 0
How to get this resultant using pandas or any other library ?

Comment: Use the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70217898/merge-two-pandas-dataframes-without-duplicating-items/70218112#70218112) with option `how='outer'` in `merge`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [merge two pandas dataframes without duplicating items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70217898/merge-two-pandas-dataframes-without-duplicating-items)

Answer (score 0):

You can try 'np.concatenate((a,b), axis=0)'